# Why AnyLogic does not shows error while building yet shows errors while running

Tags: anylogic

I made something simple:

There is a collection Point, where the truck is supposed to pick Fresh Fruit Bunch, then return to the home base:

Simulation Window Preview:

[image: Simulation Window Preview]

I do not understand why it comes up with errors. Previously I build the model and no error shows up. When I run it shows errors, which I don't understand where to troubleshoot the problem.

I am still new to AnyLogic and help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, happy to help but you should reverse your question. "Where is my error" is not helpful, we cannot do your work. You describe your error and ask how to solve it (plus show what you already did). Please study how to ask good questions, and you will get good answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Also check https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I am very new to AnyLogic, get introduced just a couple of weeks ago. I am completely lost and have no idea what error and neither I could get the idea of what should I do. But I will try to elaborate on them in the future.

Comment: no problem, we have all been there. But please make sure you ask specific questions that *can* be answered. We cannot replace learning fundamentals ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your error indicates that you run out of memory. Increase the experiment memory in the properties:
[image]

Comment: I already try to increase my memory to 8GB still no avail. any other ways to check, or what should I check?

Comment: same error? Happy to help but "Is there any other way?" is not helpful, we cannot do your work. You describe your error and ask how to solve it (plus show what you already did). Please study how to ask good questions, and you will get good answers: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Also check stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example